# Database does not attach to the project

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim db As SMSDataContext("C:\USERS\CHOUDHRY NAEEM\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\SCHOOL MANAGEMENT SOFTWARE\SCHOOL MANAGEMENT SOFTWARE\SMSDB.MDF")
Dim CheckStudentDetails = From p As db.Students
            Where p.Registration_Number = txtregno.Text
            Select p
```

The database does not attach to the project. The error occurs on the `db` variable:

> Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the [**`New` keyword**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx). I also recommend not to hardcode paths. Use [**`Path.Combine()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) together with [**`Application.StartupPath`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct a dynamic path.

```
Dim db As New SMSDataContext(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "SMSDB.MDF"))
```

Be sure to put the database in the executable directory instead of the project folder (since the latter will not exist after you release the application).